# Button does not react from the first click

Tags: javascript, html

Greeting all,

I have a problem with my button. I have created canvas function that creates a rectangular according coordinates after I click on button. However, when I open the html file, input coordinates and click on button it does not work from the first click. I should reload the page and after that the button starts working. Can you please let me know, why my button does not work from the first click? Please find my code attached.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("#can")
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
let rect1 = inp1.value
let rect2 = inp2.value
let arr1 = rect1.split("-")
let arr2 = rect2.split("-")
createcanvas.addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
    
        ctx.rect(arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], arr1[3]);
        ctx.rect(arr2[0], arr2[1], arr2[2], arr2[3]);
        ctx.stroke();
})
connect.addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(arr1[0],arr1[1])
    ctx.lineTo(arr2[0],arr2[0])
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo((+arr1[0])+(+arr1[2]),arr1[1])
    ctx.lineTo((+arr2[1])+(+arr2[2]),arr2[1])
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(arr1[0], (+arr1[1])+(+arr1[2]))
    ctx.lineTo(arr2[0], (+arr2[1])+(+arr2[2]))
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo((+arr1[0])+(+arr1[2]),(+arr1[0])+(+arr1[2]))
    ctx.lineTo((+arr2[1])+(+arr2[2]),(+arr2[1])+(+arr2[2]))
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp1">
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp2">
    <button id="createcanvas">Create</button>
    <button id="connect">Connect</button>
    <canvas id="can" width="500px" height="500px" style="background-color: olive;display:block;"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work now:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("#can");
let arr1,arr2,ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const getCoords=()=>[inp1.value.split("-").map(v=>+v),inp2.value.split("-").map(v=>+v)],
      drwline=(a,b,c,d)=>
         {ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(a,b);ctx.lineTo(c,d);ctx.stroke();ctx.closePath();}

document.getElementById("createcanvas").addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
  let [arr1,arr2]=getCoords();
  ctx.rect(...arr1);
  ctx.rect(...arr2);
  ctx.stroke();
});
document.getElementById("connect").addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
  let [[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h]]=getCoords();
  drwline(a,b,e,f);
  drwline(a+c,b,e+g,f);
  drwline(a,b+d,e,f+h);
  drwline(a+c,b+d,e+g,f+h);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp1" value="10-10-200-200">
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp2" value="20-20-230-230">
    <button id="createcanvas">Create</button>
    <button id="connect">Connect</button>
    <canvas id="can" width="500px" height="500px" style="background-color: #ccc;display:block;"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Explanation:**

I moved the input-reading section into your event handling functions for your `#createcanvas` and `#connect` buttons. For this I created the helper function `getCoords()`. This collects the input values and returns them into two arrays that are then local to the individual functions.

You should always use `document.getElementbyId()` or some suitable `document.querySelector()` function to get the DOM element reference, since otherwise the objects might get in conflict with variables declared in the global name space.

In a later edit I also shortened some of your drawing instructions, following the "DRY" (dont't repeat yourself) paradigm: the function `drwline()` now draws a line between two points.

Comment: Please refer to the "Explanation" below the snippet.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: @AramayisYeghiazaryan : If you wish [answer response](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Aramayis Yeghiazaryan, if your problem has been solved, please upvote and mark it as the correct answer.